# VScode terminal output

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VS Code and writing the easy sample "hello world" program to make sure everything runs but when inspecting the terminal output im getting a lot of extra text and nothing is actually outputting into the output window. I've got a screen of what it's displaying and it just seems wrong to me. I can't seem to find anything online, but I just wanna determine if I have the programs installed into conflicting directories or what.

Comment: PS C:\Users\silph\OneDrive\Documents\HelloWorld> cd 'c:\Users\silph\OneDrive\Documents\HelloWorld'; & 'C:\Users\silph\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.24.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Users\silph\AppData\Local\Programs\AdoptOpenJDK\bin\java' '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:50083' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\silph\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\4be957a85695cf8d7af29a8dcced48d4\redhat.java\jdt_ws\HelloWorld_c221cec2\bin' 'Quickstart'
Hello World
Stupid output
PS C:\Users\silph\OneDrive\Documents\HelloWorld>

Comment: this is the output in the terminal window